# Python equivalent of PHP mysql_fetch_array

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I would like to fetch an array in MySQL. Can someone please tell me how to use Python using MySQLdb to do so?

For example, this is what I would like to do in Python:

```
<?php

  require_once('Config.php'); 

  $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = 'namehere'");
  $data = mysql_fetch_array($q);
  echo $data['lastname'];

?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install MySQLdb (the drivers for MySQL for Python). Type `pip install mysql-python`
2. Read up on the [Python DB API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), which is the standard way to access databases in Python.

Then, try this:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> connection = MySQLdb.connect(database='test')
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = %s',('somename',))
>>> results = cursor.fetchall()
>>> for i in results:
       print i
```

Comment: It is worrying this is the only answer with some form of SQL escaping.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just have one more question. When I use this, data is returned in this format: (('dave',), ('jake',)). How can I edit the format of this data, so it is like this ('dave', 'jake'). I am looping through the data that is returned and using each as a variable. This would be much easier to manipulate for my purpose. Thanks again.

Comment: `names = [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]`

Answer (score 15):

In python you have `dictionary=True`, I have tested in python3. This returns directory which is much similar to associative array in php.
eg.

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',host='127.0.0.1',database='test1')
cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
sql= ("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id>0")
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use this (**dictionary=True**):

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',host='127.0.0.1', database='test1')

cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")

for row in cursor:
    print(row['column'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html). Something like this would do the trick:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://username:password@host:port/database')
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("select username from users")
for row in result:
    print "username:", row['username']
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import MySQLdb
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",  # your host
                     user="root",  # username
                     passwd="password",  # password
                     db="frateData")  # name of the database)
cursor = connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = %s',['namehere'])
data = cursor.fetchall()
print data['lastname']
```

Please note that by initiating your cursor by passing the following parameter: "MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor"
a list instead of an array is returned so you can reference the data with their key name, which in your case in lastname.